# TeamCity non blocking BuildType

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm looking for a way to create a BuildType that is optional and won't block the build process.

We have a complex build pipeline, one of the BuildTypes is very slow and blocks the build from finishing, the BuildType is not actually necessary in order to complete the build, it's just TypeScript type checking, so we do want to see the results but don't want to wait for it to finish.

Already tried to add it as a dependency with `FailureAction.IGNORE` the problem with that is that even if the build fails TeamCity still waiting for it to finish.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could split your build configuration into two: first one for the main part, and a dependent one with TypeScript stuff. Second build would start on "dependency change", but the first build would already be finished. Seems like what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching a response I got from TeamCity support:
If the build triggered by the pull request (PR) has a dependency, it will need to wait for the dependency to build, regardless of the onDependencyFailure value.

If you need the build to be independent of some build step, that build step needs to:

be moved into a separate build configuration;
not be the PR build's dependency.
To trigger TypeScript type checking configuration when the PR build starts, you can add a Finish Build Trigger to the TypeScript type checking configuration and point it to the PR build. If you need any artifacts from the PR build, you can download them in the build script via REST API.

Additionally, if the PR build is triggered frequently and there can be more than one build of the PR build configuration running or queued at a time, I'd recommend triggering the TypeScript type checking configuration via REST API as well, instead of using the Finish Build Trigger because of this issue.